# Addressing localhost from a virtualbox virtual Window10 vm

Tags: windows-10, localhost, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am a front end developer. I am using a Mac and try to access Microsoft Edge browser (Windows 10) to debug some of the cross browser problem. But I am not able to point the VirtualBox windows10 VM localhost to my local server. I followed instructions I could fond online and set the default gateway of VM points to "localhost", as seen in the following screen shot taken from virtual windows 10 machine, but still could not make it work.

I can use "http://10.0.2.2:3000" to access my local server on Mac, but "http://localhost:3000" did not work. This causes problem when pages navigate and the url domain automatically change back to "localhost".

BTW, this problem does not exist in Windows 7 VM.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm currently running into the exact same issue. Adding "10.0.2.2 localhost" works in the default Microsoft Windows 7 IE11 VM, but not in their Windows 8 Edge VM. Did you ever find a fix? Will report back if I figure it out.

Comment: @Kevin No fix yet. Not sure how to deal with it yet.

Comment: Okay thanks @Jun Q! We will be looking at the issue more closely later this week and hopefully we'll find something.